3D action movie about pizza boy who discovers himself in the middle of intergalactic war
I'm looking for 2000–2010 3D action movie about a pizza boy who discovers himself in the middle of intergalactic war.
One day he delivers pizza to a girl's dancing school. Once he arrived, he was hiding and staring at dancing girls. The dancers catch him staring and he's scared and hits the floor. The dancers run out and start laughing at him. One of the dancers likes him and they went to meadow and start dancing.
The dancer will be killed by aliens, after that he will be chosen with 2 other guys (one a captain in the Air Force, the other a little boy who fights Karate) to guard earth. Then one of the aliens (female) will join them. This pizza boy is a First Knight.
They have big robots and fight big robots also...

I think this is the Korean movie Elysium (2003).
It's not live action in fact but the other details seem to match up.
BeyondHollywood.com

With “Elysium”, our hero is Van, a pizza delivery guy who is in love with a ballerina who subsequently gets fried by an Elysian mecha. Later, Van’s life is saved by Nix, an Elysian who switches sides and becomes Van’s substitute girlfriend. 

KoreanFilm.org

The attack occurs just as Van is about to win the Turbo Pinball race. Fiery death rains down from the sky as the Elysium call for the end of the human race for the violent ways.  Millions die in the initial attack and even more fall as the aliens send swarms of spider robots and elite warriors wearing giant robot suits of armor to eliminate the survivors.  
The humans that were not killed in the initial strikes are forced to live in underground shelters while the Earth Defense fights a losing battle against the attackers. Van and Lydia take shelter in one such place, but as time passes, Lydia starts to pine for the sun prompting the pair to risk a trip to a grassy hillside where they used to date.  Unfortunately, their timing was bad and they are caught in the crossfire between the armies of Earth and Elysium. Kronos, wearing the armor of a giant warrior, takes aim and kills the fleeing young woman leading to a change in gentle Van. In mourning and bearing a deep hatred for the Elysium, especially Kronos, he joins the resisting forces.
However, in what seems to be his first mission, his entire squad is wiped out except for Van who is saved at last minute by first Nix, a platinum-haired beauty from Elysium and then the mysterious Son-ra who teleports Van to her base beneath the sands of a wasteland. There, Van joins Paul and Christopher as part of Son-ra’s last line of defense to keep the powerful Triad Weapon out of the hands of General Necros of the Elysium.


Yes. You find it. Thanks a lot!
